# payumoney payment gateway integration in codeigniter with multiple payment buttons in asingle page? will it work?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, payment-gateway, payumoney

i would like to integrate pay u money payment gateway in my website. but i don't have cart option. i would like to display multiple products in a single page and i want to give buy option for individual product, shall i need to repeat form for every product or is there any option to achieve this??

above image displaying that i have written pay u money form for a single product

[code for a single form in my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suHoY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what do you want exactly, but I think you want more buttons on a form giving different results. `input type="submit"` also has a `name=""` field, and on the recieving php form can check which submit button was pressed with

```
$submitname = $_POST['buttonname'];
(if ($submitname = "something") {
    //enter your code here
})
```